# How to apply a layer to multiple open images in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, batch-processing

I am using **Photoshop CS6**.  I have 40 images that have a transparent background open.  I would like to apply a layer (a fill with gradient) to each of the 40 images without having to manually select `Duplicate Layer` (because I can only select one document at at time as a destination).

Any advice?

Answer (score 7):

Perfect scenario for a **Batch Action**.

You'll need to perform the action once to record what you want to do, then setup a Batch Action under **File > Automate > Batch**.

At, least that's where to find it on CS3-CS5.

Comment: It's still there in CC... :-)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to @ckpepper02's very practical answer is to set up the Action then select all the target files in Bridge and run `Tools > Photoshop > Batch...`. This gets you to the same place, and even runs the same script, but the convenience of selecting the files ahead of time in Bridge can make this faster and more convenient.